# mod_rewrite redirects instead of rewriting URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting

Good day everyone,

I have an HTACCESS file that contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/public/$1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

The purpose of the code is that when the user types my domain name 'mydomain.com', it will not call the mydomain.com/index.php, instead it will call the mydomain.com/public/index.php without the user noticing the redirect (or internal redirects).

I got the code on some website and it works on my local machine (WAMP stack).
The problem is, when I transfer it now to a shared hosting server, then an external redirect occurs instead of an internal one. Example:

Typing mydomain.com would then be mydomain.com/public in the address bar.

I already checked the hosting server's configuration and yes,

- HTACCESS are enabled.
- mod_rewrite is enabled.
- I can modify PHP settings using an HTACCESS file.

The shared hosting server implements the LAMP stack.

Any idea on what I'm missing? Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

All my rewrites are redirecting not only that code which are perfectly working on my local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `http://mydomain.com` in your rule's target. It tells the rewrite engine to redirect instead of internally rewriting.

Comment: I'll try that, but could you explain why the redirect does not happen in my machine? e.i. using localhost? Thanks!

Comment: @eGzg0t no idea why, it should always redirect when you have that. Are you sure it's the same version of apache?

Comment: No, they are different, mine is updated...I'm not sure about the version of the hosting site but for sure it is close to the latest version.

Comment: that did it. But its very weird. Thanks anyway!